# Can I get a notification on my iPhone when I receive a certain email?

Tags: iphone, email, gmail, notifications, mobile-mail

I need to be able to reply to just 1 email that I irregularly receive within seconds of it arriving.  I want my iPhone to start vibrating etc. when it arrives.

Email is from info@meetup.com (the meetup website).  Problem is I only want to be notified when 1 of about 100 emails/month arrive.

That target email can only be identified based on a text string in its body content together with its email subject line. It's not (not able to be) coming from a special email address nor is it able to be set to go to a unique address for myself.  (They use 1 email they send from and I am limited to 1 email address to use to receive all 100 emails.)

I use gmail and Apple Mail on the Mac and have an iPhone.  But my Mac is not on all the time.

How do I get my iPhone to vibrate at me when this email arrives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible on your iPhone. I searched for a bit if there was a third party email application which had this feature.

If I where you I would look into IFTTT (If This Then That). I'm on my phone now so could not try if you could read body text from emails. But there is a trigger->action: [Get a notification when you get a new email with a specific label](https://ifttt.com/applets/xrDE7KnB-get-a-notification-when-you-get-a-new-email-with-a-specific-label).

I'm not a Gmail user, but I guess you can make rules.

1. Make a rule that looks for incoming mail and scan for the subject or text in body and apply that label to that new email message.
2. Make a trigger->action in IFTTT. Let IFTTT watch your Gmail for any new messages with that specific label. IFTTT wil send you a push notification.

Comment: This works almost perfectly.  Thanks.  I set a "filter" inside gmail to watch for the body and subject text arriving.  Then gmail assigns a "label" to this email.  Then IFTTT is watching for that label and sends a notification to my iPhone.  Do you know why there is a big white rectangle saying "file not found" in the IFTTT notification?

Comment: Your welcome :-) I'm not sure.. will try when I'm home again. Will let you know!